# Jailbroken when I am not? On Android?

Tags: rooting

I bought 4 TVs ([Magnum 32" Android TV MAGE32DOAS35S](http://luxsamltd.com/products/magnum/televisions-1/magnum-32-smart-led-tv.html)) that run Android 4.4.2 Kitkat. I've installed my local IPTV app ([Digicel Play Multiscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.huawei.digicel)) onto them hoping that I would be able to watch tv, apparently whenever I launch channels it says:

> Error Jailbroken.

Now I am confused, I downloaded several root checker apps but all of them says that I am not rooted. What can the problem possibly be? Is it the TV or the app itself?

Comment: "Jailbreaking" is only a thing on iPhones, not Android. I suspect the developer of this app doesn't know what they're doing.

Comment: To get some more specific answers, you'll need to [edit] your question to give more specific details: what Android TVs are these? Which is your "local IPTV app"?

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking and to clear all things up I live in a 3rd world country. The TV is a [Magnum 32" Android TV MAGE32DOAS35S](http://luxsamltd.com/products/magnum/televisions-1/magnum-32-smart-led-tv.html) it was manufactured locally so there is little info on it. As for the IPTV app it's [Digicel Play Multiscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.huawei.digicel&hl=en)

Comment: Sounds like your TV is partially rooted, which is a thing. (Don't ask me why)

Comment: Strange because I've heard things about custom ROM and unlocked bootloader and all that stuff which claims that it is partially rooted as well.

Comment: To find out whether it's the app or the device, I'd try a different app. I'm not familiar with Android TV – but if standard Android apps run on it, you can find a few candidates [in my corresponding app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_video_tv#group_349).

Comment: I'm afraid it's the iptv app because I tried some german iptv apps in your repository and worked very well as of this point I am very confused 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android version running on these is probably not supporting OEM and DRMs codecs / encryptions. You should check the manufacturer for more details about this.